# How to read user information from Google Sign-in Token WebApi core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, google-signin

First of all, I'm not using Identity, I already have the user Token from a android client-side and I need to get the Email from this Token. I read [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/authentication-using-google-in-asp-net-core-2-0-5ec32c803e23) article about implement but it uses Identity and the Google Sign-In is inside a view, not what I want. Theres a [.NET API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth), but it's not what I want.

There's a Rest API to get a email from token ? Thanks!

Comment: How did you generate the sign-in token? Could you share us the test token? Do you want to get the email from token in the client or web api?

Comment: The Token was generated by a Android Client with the Sign in API. I want to get the token from the client in the web api!

Comment: Check [Additional fields (claims?) needed in GoogleJsonWebSignature.cs's Payload class #1040](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1040) and [Validate Google ID Token in a .Net backend server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090396/validate-google-id-token-in-a-net-backend-server)